# Joining two Pandas DataFrames does not work anymore?

Tags: join, pandas, merge, dataframe

I have 2 Pandas Dataframes.

The first one looks like this:

```
date           rank   id       points
2010-01-04     1      100001   10550
2010-01-04     2      100002    9205
```

The second one like this:

```
id       name   
100001   A    
100002   B
```

I want to join both dataframes via the `id` column. So the result should look like:

```
date           rank    id       points  name  
2010-01-04     1       100001   10550   A    
2010-01-04     2       100002    9205   B
```

Some weeks ago I wrote code for that, but for some reason it does not work anymore. I end up with an empty dataframe after I execute this code for joining:

```
join = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='id')
```

Why is `join` empty?

Comment: aah, there seems to be an issue with the ID columns. for df1 they are of type object, and for df2 they are ints. hence, join does not work...

Comment: Please edit to include the result of `print(df1["id"])` and `print(df2["id"]))` (which is likely to show the problem.) --update: and it looks like that was the issue. :-)  You're probably comparing strings with integers.  You can answer your own question now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short story: as pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867277/joining-two-pandas-dataframes-does-not-work-anymore?noredirect=1#comment49776347_30867277) already, i was comparing strings with integers.

long story: i didn't expect python to parse the id-columns of two input csv files to different datatpyes. df1.id was of type Object. df2.id was of type int. and i needed to find out why df1.id was parsed to Object and not automatically to int, because it only contained numbers.

turns out that it had something to do with the encoding of my CSV file. in notepad++ the file was encoded as plain UTF-8. it seems that pandas did not like this, because when i tried to convert the id column to int, it raised an error like `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\ufeff100001'`. The number `100001` is the first ID of the first row. So there seems to be some encoded character before this number (at the very beginning of the file) `\ufeff` that prevented pandas to parse the whole column as int. in notepad++ i then changed the encoding of the file to `UTF-8 without BOM` and then everything worked.